# Trying to install dnsmasq on osx via brew

Tags: macos, homebrew, dnsmasq

Trying to install dnsmasq but looks like the symlink is not working

```
~/Dev/elixir/elixir_group master*
❯ brew link dnsmasq
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/dnsmasq/2.80...
Error: Could not symlink sbin/dnsmasq
/usr/local/sbin is not writable.
```

thoughts?

Edit: learned I needed to create the sbin for myself in osx mojave.

Answer (score 0):

For osx mojave just didn't exist, creating it myself fixed the issue.

Now I just need to make sure its in my path correctly.